# my session values goes null in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

here is my code

```
var _tblPatient = _dc.tblPatients.Where(p => p.nUserId == GlobalUid).FirstOrDefault();

if (Patienttbn.Checked == true && _tblPatient == null)
{
    if (_tblDonor != null)
    {
        if (_tblDonor.strStatus == "start")
        {
            _tblDonor.strStatus = "close";
            _tblDonor.dtAddDate = DateTime.Now;
            // _dc.tblDonors
            _dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    _tblPatient.nUserId = GlobalUid;
    _tblPatient.strStatus = "start";
    _tblPatient.dtAddDate = DateTime.Now;
    _dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

my code sends exception of object reference not set to an instance what I believe is my session goes null

> GlobalUid

gets the session value it works till the

> _dc.SubmitChanges();

but throws exception on

> _tblPatient.nUserId = GlobalUid;

Comment: The session can be null, in face any value can be null - for many reasons, debug your code, locate the real issue.

Comment: Did you try to convert session to GUID datatype?

Comment: I have seen this issue before I would suggest actually initializing the Session variable in the gloabal.asax to something like this 
`HttpContext.Current.Session["somesessionvariable"] = string.Empty`
You should look at doing something like this in this msdn posting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you guys can see in the line var _tblPatient = _dc.tblPatients.Where(p => p.nUserId == GlobalUid).FirstOrDefault();    GlobalUid is there = it is not null and it is retrieving the information from the database, but  in the below code it does not work

Comment: @user3819586 That doesn't necessarily mean `GlobalUid` isn't `null` all the time. Your code only executes whenever `_tblPatient` is null as in no `_tblPatient` is found. Have you verified that `GlobalUid` in fact isn't `null` when stepping through the code? Perhaps you could post the code inside the `GlobalUid` property?

Comment: yes it is not null I can see the value but when it comes on the line _tblPatient.nUserId = GlobalUid; it throws exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new object for

> _tblPatient = new tblPatient();

It will solve your problem